# Unable to play video on exoplayer on android 11

Tags: android, exoplayer

The following code seems to be working fine on android 10 and below - but on android 11 video doesn't play and I get the following error

**onPlayerError - Source error**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_play);

        playerView = findViewById(R.id.playerView);
        exoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
        playerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);

        if (getIntent() != null)
        {
            String videoPath = getIntent().getExtras().getString(VIDEO_PATH);

            Log.d(TAG,"intent not null");
            Log.d(TAG,"videoPath = "+videoPath);
            Log.d(TAG,"video URI from file= "+Uri.fromFile(new File(videoPath)));

            Uri videoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                this, VideoPlayerActivity.this.getPackageName() + ".provider",
                new File(videoPath));

            Log.d(TAG,"video URI from FileProvider = "+videoURI);

            MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(
                    Uri.fromFile(new File(videoPath))
            );

            exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
            exoPlayer.prepare();
            exoPlayer.play();
            exoPlayer.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"onPlayerError - "+error.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onMetadata(Metadata metadata) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"onMetadata - "+metadata.toString());
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(TAG,"something is null");
        }
    }
```

I have tried to get the URI of the video using both the approaches and neither works. Is there any way to make it work?

The code that saves the video in previous activity -

```
String fileName = SR_PreferencesHelper.getString(SR_PreferencesHelper.KEY_FILE_NAME_PREFIX, "recording") + "_" + new SimpleDateFormat(SR_PreferencesHelper.getString(SR_PreferencesHelper.KEY_FILE_NAME_FOMART, Config.itemsFileNameFomart[0].getValue())).format(new Date()) + ".mp4";
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES + File.separator + context.getString(R.string.app_name));
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);
        Uri mUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
```

Also, this function works fine -

```
public void openMediaUsingOtherApps(String filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    getContext(), getContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
                    new File(filePath));

            Intent openVideoIntent = new Intent();
            openVideoIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    .setDataAndType(
                            fileUri,
                            getContext().getContentResolver().getType(fileUri));
            getContext().startActivity(openVideoIntent);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG,"openMediaUsingOtherApps, msg - "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `videoPath`? Where are you getting it from?

Comment: @CommonsWare - videoPath is being passed from an activity that saves video to the storage - video plays perfectly fine when played using other video players. I even checked the location to see if the video is being created at the desired location and it is.